# Как сохранить модель ManyToMany в django ORM?

Tags: python, django, база-данных, orm

Не получается сохранить данные в таблицу со связью многие-ко-многим

Сохраняю так:

```
new_subscriber = EventToSubscriber(event=event_id, subscriber=current_user)
new_subscriber.save()
```

Модель:

```
class EventToSubscriber(Model):
    event = models.ManyToManyField(Event, verbose_name='Событие')
    subscriber = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name='Подписчик')
```

Выдает мне:

```
TypeError at /subscribe/4
Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use event.set() instead.
```

Comment: new_subscriber = EventToSubscriber.objects.create()
new_subscriber.event.add(event_id)
new_subscriber.subscriber.add(current_user)

Работает так

Answer (score 0):

Как написано в ошибке, вы не можете напрямую создавать связи. Для манипуляции с m2m значениями, используйте методы `set`, `add`, `remove` и `clear`

Почитать подробнее можно в [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)